# Two wi-fi networks fighting over some IP addresses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, routing

I presently have two wi-fi adapters running on my laptop.

- The one with the highest priority is connected to my phone's wi-fi tethering, and I've been assigned a dynamic IP address usually around 192.168.43.5. (IP address and subnet configuration can't be changed, because it's an unrooted phone.)
- My second network is a LAN exclusively. Right now it's running with a subnet mask of **255.0.0.0** (my best guess) and a default gateway of **10.0.0.1**.

Unfortunately, sometimes my phone will redirect to an image compression service hosted at **1.1.1.1** or **1.1.1.2**. When this happens, images will fail to load on some websites. When I attempt to open the images, I'm taken to my LAN router's configuration page, hosted at 10.0.0.1.

Something is amok here. How do I set up my LAN router's IP address assignment and subnet mask to keep from interfering with my wi-fi hotspot? There's precious little information about it online, even when I search for info about private subnet masks.

My local network config is as follows:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d4d6:b65b:6db4:9630%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::44e5:80c3:809e:2055%40
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
```

When loading images, often my URLs look like this:

```
1.1.1.2/bmi/readwrite.com/files/styles/630_0su/public/fields/shutterstock_118925992.jpg
```

A tracert to it yields the following (it goes to the wrong, local, router:

```
Tracing route to 1.1.1.2 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  router.belkin [10.0.0.1]
  2  router.belkin [10.0.0.1]  reports: Destination net unreachable.
```

My "route print" output, as requested:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...a4 17 31 de 96 0f ......Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network
ter
 40...ec 1a 59 0f 94 29 ......Surf Wireless Micro USB Adapter
 39...00 ff 56 0f 3f e2 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 34...02 00 54 74 68 72 ......EasyTether Network Adapter
 22...00 26 37 bd 39 42 ......PdaNet Broadband Adapter
 13...54 53 ed 37 9c 49 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 25...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.43.1     192.168.43.5     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1         10.0.0.2     25
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    281
         10.0.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    281
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.43.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.43.5    281
     192.168.43.5  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.43.5    281
   192.168.43.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.43.5    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.43.5    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.43.5    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 18    306 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 18    306 2001::/32                On-link
 18    306 2001:0:9d38:6abd:d8:f97:3f57:d4fa/128
                                    On-link
 40    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 15    281 fe80::5efe:10.0.0.2/128  On-link
 25    286 fe80::5efe:192.168.43.5/128
                                    On-link
 18    306 fe80::d8:f97:3f57:d4fa/128
                                    On-link
 40    281 fe80::44e5:80c3:809e:2055/128
                                    On-link
 12    281 fe80::d4d6:b65b:6db4:9630/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 40    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: based on what you are describing, somthing is misconfigured. could you please post the IP configuration for both interfaces of your LAN router? if you nslookup or dig the domain name where the images are hosted, what server responds and with what IP?

Comment: @FrankThomas Adding them shortly -- but the images are hosted at 1.1.1.1/bmi/[remote/location/of/file/here] ... details to follow.

Comment: if you are accessing the server by IP address, that implies it must be a routing issue then, and your tracert backs that up. whats the output of `route print` on your laptop?

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for the input; I couldn't deduce anything about this specific address in "route print" so I left it for you in its entirety. 192.168... is presumably the wi-fi hotspot, 10.0... should be the LAN.

Comment: it shows you have two routes to 0.0.0.0 with the same metric, one for each nic, so windows can't decide which interface to use. you can try `route delete 0.0.0.0` to remove one of them, and see if it fixes the issue temporarilly, but I can't guarantee that it will delete the right one (10.0.0.2). do you have Adobe CS3 installed or somthing else that uses the bonjour service (iTunes mayhap)? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/765aa1c6-dd9a-4447-9de0-aecc41498b04/windows-7-two-default-gateway-0000?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must delete both default routes, then re-establish the one you want (via 192.168.43.1) as the "sole" default gateway. From a Terminal, type:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0
route delete 0.0.0.0
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.43.1 metric 1
```

To make this permanent, replace in the last command route with route -p

Comment: Success! Only one "route delete" worked, but as of now there is an active route and a persistent route both connecting the address 0.0.0.0, with the netmask 0.0.0.0, to 192.168.43.1, as it should be. All is well in the world.